# Numbers at the corners of concentric squares

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

[image]

Put 4 distinct 1 digit non-negative numbers (A, B, C, D) to every vertex of a rectangle.
Then put the last digit of the sum of 2 connected vertexes at the sides of the rectangle.
Create smaller rectangle connecting the sides of the bigger rectangle.
Do above procedure once more (using the 4 new numbers which do not have to be distinct).
**The last 4 numbers must be the same.**
Then sum (A, B, C, D), let’s call it  X.

```
E = last digit of (A+B)           G = last digit of (B+D)
H = last digit of (C+D)           F = last digit of (A+C)
I = last digit of (F+E)           J = last digit of (E+G)
K = last digit of (F+H)           L = last digit of (H+G)
I = J = K = L
```

Find (A, B, C, D) with the smallest X

Bonus Puzzle : Find (A, B, C, D) with the largest X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the last four to all be equal the middle four must be

> a rotation of $(n,m,m,n)$ with $m-n \pmod{10}=5$ (with ns and ms on opposite corners).

The only way to do that is to have the first four be

> some rotation of $(p,q,r,s)$ with $p+q \pmod{10}=r+s \pmod{10}$
>  while $p+r=q+s$

The smallest solution in $X$ is thus

> $12$ with $A,B,C,D$ some rotation of $(0,1,6,5)$ or $(1,0,5,6)$

The largest would be

> $24$ with $A,B,C,D$ some rotation of $(3,4,9,8)$ or $(4,3,8,9)$

Comment: Oh sory my question was wrong, I have edited it, the second rectangle do not have to be distinct. There are solutions for this question.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya - how is it now?

Comment: you are correct now !

Comment: Only thing I missed: the first condition means there are twice as many solutions as I suggest... fixing

Comment: pretty sure i had the complete solution before ya, but we both got there. nice job :)

Comment: @Rubio Thanks, you too! You just gotta type quicker and leave the details for immediate edits :) (see my notification to Jamal above about 4 mins before your post, about 1 min after I undeleted).

Answer (score 3):

Minimum sum of A, B, C, D is

> **12** - using 0,1,5,6 such that each side totals 1, 6, or 11;
>  e.g. A=0, B=1, C=6, D=5 gives sides AB=1, BD=6, AC=6, CD=11.
>  this uses values 0 and 1 to minimize the sum, and matches them with the lowest complementary pair that gives usable modulus values after summing with the neighbors.

This gives E, F, G, H of

> alternating ones and sixes

which in turn gives I/J/K/L of

> 7, by adding a one and a six.

There are multiple solutions that fit

> 8 total, actually.
>  0,1,6,5; 0,6,1,5; 1,0,5,6; 1,5,0,6;
>  5,1,6,0; 5,6,1,0; 6,0,5,1; 6,5,0;1.

Bonus -

> Largest total sum is **24** by essentially the opposite method -
>  using 8 and 9 to maximize the digit sum, and matching them with the complementary values 3 and 4 to give pairable modulus sums of 7, 12, and 17.
>  e.g. A=9, B=8, C=3, D=4 (for sides AB=17, BD=12, AC=12, CD=7)
>  and then the E,F,G,H values are alternating 2s and 7s,
>  summing to I/J/K/L of 9.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

> 1^^^^3^^^^2
>  ^^^1^^^1^^^
>  8^^^^^^^^^8
>  ^^^1^^^1^^^
>  7^^^^3^^^^6

The lowest sum should be $1+2+7+6=16$(I don't include zero)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

> X=(1,4,9,6) or (2,3,8,7) or (3,2,7,8) or (4,1,6,9).
>  Getting a second rectangle of 0-5-0-5 is the only way I found so far and every solutions are = 20 so no lowest or smallest.

Comment: +1 as the first true answer, but still not the smallest or the largest one.